# Story about a boy with gills who travelled in seaweed and kids who travelled with him could breathe underwater

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

My friend and I were trying to remember a book we read in middle school in the 1980s.

It was about a boy who arrived with seaweed.  He had gills and webbed hands and feet and land children were able to swim with him and breathe underwater as they travelled in the seaweed.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you'll see this, but I was searching for the same book - it was driving me crazy!

It's *[Splashman](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5855862-splashman)* by Lydia Weaver.

[image: Front cover of Splashman]

> A fantasy adventure about a boy--part fish, part human--who spirits away a band of children and leads them on an expedition through the ocean depths. Shy, bookish Jane is both intrigued and suspicious about the charming but mysterious Peter Joyce until he and ten other kids disappear from the beach one night, in this fantastical undersea adventure from the author of Close to Home and Child Star.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much ♡